# Bounce 0 & Delivery 100% in EXM when that isn't true: need to edit a config?

Tags: exm

I've read through others' issues and responses, but have not seen a reference to the config file, `Sitecore.EDS.Providers.CustomSmtp.Sync.config`. We have set up a `pop3 server` and checked `collect notifications` in the Email Preference Center under Delivery Status Notifications.

But do we also have to edit the fields in the config? I checked this file and see nothing in there reflecting our pop3.

Thanks.